# Is there a way to implement layers in GDI+?

Tags: c++, gdi+

My idea would be to draw several Graphics objects on memory and combine them when drawing the image.

But I haven't got a precise idea of how to do that. Shall I use GraphicsContainer's? Or save the objects as Metafile's? (these are temporary objects, I would like to keep them on memory)

Answer (score 1):

Simplest method: create multiple bitmaps. Draw what you want to them. Composite them by drawing them back to front.

If you have a lot of text, then using a metafile for those layer(s) may improve the rendering quality somewhat.